# Present a new image every time the app is open

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am trying to put a new image every time someone closes and reopens the app.

This is a sample view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("PictureName")
    }
}

struct SwiftUIiew_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a constant that is an array of images.

```
let images: [String] = ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4"]
```

Then when you call the constant inside Image modify it with random element

```
 Image(images.randomElement()!)
```

im force unwrapping it which is for demo only and not recommended.